# seekbar's background picture showed twice

Tags: android, seekbar

Progress bar display twice.

[image]

My XML code:

[image]

Style :

[image]

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can add **gradient** like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:endColor="@color/colorgreenheader"
        android:centerColor="@color/color_neartowhite"
        android:startColor="@color/color_grey_light" />

    <corners android:radius="8sp" />
    <size android:width="8sp"/>
    <padding
        android:left="0.5sp"
        android:right="0.5sp" />

</shape>
```